# The sorter.setRowFilter method does not work properly

Tags: java

```
    MyPanel HDSPanel = new MyPanel();
    myTableHeader = new String[] {"A1", "A2", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T7", "T8"};
    HDSPanel.addPanel(tabbedPane, "My First Table","HDS Table", myTableHeader);
    
    MyPanel ISPanel = new MyPanel();
    myTableHeader = new String[] {"A1", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", , myTableHeader);
    ISPanel.addPanel(tabbedPane, "My Second Table","IS Table", myTableHeader);  

  public void myFilter(String searchText, JTable mytable, int columnNumber) {
    model = mytable.getModel();
    final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
    mytable.setRowSorter(sorter);
    if (searchText.length() == 0) {
        sorter.setRowFilter(null);
        
    } else {
        try {
            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + searchText, columnNumber));

        } catch (PatternSyntaxException pse) {
            System.out.println("Bad regex pattern");
        }
    }

}
```

The above method is inside a class called MyPanel. I am running another method in the same class to add a panel to the existing TabbedPane. Thus, by creating MyPanel object, I get two panels in TabbedPane.

I am also creating a textfield. When there is a change in the text of the textfield, the rows in the table are filtered according to this change. So far everything works fine on the first panel.

However, in the second panel, sorter.setRowFilter(null) is running, but for example the sorter.setRowFilter("test") filter does not work and the table disappears. When I delete the text in the textfield, this table in the second panel comes back again.

Comment: I have solved the problem. The problem is columnNumber which refers the column which doesn't exist!..